# Sending FormData to Spring boot rest API get bad request 400

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I built my API using spring boot.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/users/profile-picture/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object updateProfilePicture(Principal principal, @ModelAttribute UpdateProfilePictureDTO profile_picture){
        Long user_id = accessTokenHandler.getIdByPrincipal(principal);
        if(user_id == null)
            return new DefaultResponseDTO(201,ResponseStatus.INVALID_USER,"No such user.");

        if(profile_picture.getProfile_picture() == null)
            return new DefaultResponseDTO(201,ResponseStatus.MISSING_INPUTS,"Profile Picture is missing.");

        return userService.updateProfilePicture(user_id, profile_picture.getProfile_picture());
    }
```

I want to send an image file to this controller. I tried with react.js. First I build formData and append the image into form data.

```
let formData = new FormData()
 formData.append(
         'profile_picture',
          newFileList[0],
      )
```

React API end point,

```
export async function profilePictureUpdate(formData) {
    //image must be send as formdata

    const response = await http.post(
        apiEndPoint + '/profile-picture/update',
        formData,
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${getJwt()}`,
                "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
            }
        });
    console.log("response of profile picuter", response);
    return response


}
```

But when submit an image file, get a 400 bad request. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Boot (2.4.x)**: replace `@ModelAttribute UpdateProfilePictureDTO profile_picture` with `@RequestParam(value = "profile_picture") MultipartFile file` and then process the `file`. Make sure `MultipartAutoConfiguration` enabled ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.spring-mvc.switch-off-dispatcherservlet)). If you registered a servlet via [`ServletRegistrationBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletRegistrationBean.html)  add multipart config to it:

```java
servletRegistrationBean.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp",
        multipartProperties.getMaxFileSize(),
        multipartProperties.getMaxRequestSize(),
        multipartProperties.getFileSizeThreshold()));
```